# Hello, I need the initial date in which a table was first uploaded / pushed vs created / modified

Tags: t-sql

I need the initial date in which a table was first uploaded / pushed **vs** created / modified.

When I use this code

```
SELECT CONCAT(ic.TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', st.name) as TableName
   ,st.create_date
   ,st.modify_date

FROM sys.tables st
```

I get the last refresh, which is usually mid night yesterday, however I need the date in which the table was made available/uploaded to the server.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this SQL Server or another brand of SQL database?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few system views you can use for this, to complete your query try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(ic.TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', st.name) as TableName
   ,st.create_date
   ,st.modify_date

FROM sys.tables st
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables ic ON st.name = ic.TABLE_NAME
```

> **NOTE:**
>   depending on your schema management, the create date may not be what you expect.
>   If the table is `DROP`'ed and the re-`CREATE TABLE`'ed (not `ALTER TABLE`), then the create_date will have the timestamp from when the `CREATE TABLE` was executed.

Comment: Yes, i believe your note about schema management is true, because the refresh date seems to override the drop date.

Comment: If you really need to track schema changes, then you can look into DDL triggers, something like this will get you started: https://jackworthen.com/2018/03/19/creating-a-log-table-to-track-changes-to-database-objects-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

This will also provide you with the desired results:

```
select
    name    [Table Name]
,   crdate  [Creation Date]
,   refdate [Refresh Date]
from    sysobjects
where   xtype = 'U'
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you so much! unfortunately, i am getting the last refresh dates in both. I appreciate your help.